# como puedo hacer para que desde un Select me aparezca otro Select Vue y Quasar

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3, vue-router, quasar

como puedo hacer para que al momento de escoger "COMPAÑIAS" me aparezca otro campo de select y cuando pongo "INTERVENTORIA" no aparezca nada de input, select en VUE y QUAZAR, 'en el de interventoría me toco comentar ese campo para el ejemplo'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el codigo que llevas hecho?

Comment: La verdad no he podido hacer esa parte de codigo, ya que no se como se hace, o como se utiliza, he visto que con un watch pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude hacerlo con watch, para que me aparesca o desaparezca el input dependiendo de la opcion que se escoja